# Serve files from a different directory when request comes to root directory

Tags: go, mux, go-http

I am having some trouble serving some files from a subdirectory when a client request comes in at the root directory.

I am using `gorilla/mux` to serve files. Here is my code below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/zhughes3/zacharyhughes.com/configparser"
)

var config configparser.Configuration

func main() {
    config := configparser.GetConfiguration()
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    initFileServer(r)

    server := &http.Server{
        Handler:      r,
        Addr:         ":" + config.Server.Port,
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}

func initFileServer(r *mux.Router) {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/"))
    r.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/", fs))
}
```

The code that creates the file system is in the `initFileServer` function above.

Currently, it serves the static files as intended when the user goes to `localhost:3000/public/`. However, I want the files to be served when the user goes to `localhost:3000/`.

I tried changing the ParsePrefix function call to `r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/", fs))` but it did not work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...I am pretty new with Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file server is already serving files under `/public`, so you don't need to strip the prefix from the http path. This should work:

```
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/",fs))
```